# Triangulation (position location) on a plane

Tags: geometry, triangulation

I'm trying to solve a problem that to me is "triangulation" but searching to see if it's been answered before makes me think that this word has a different meaning to pure mathematicians.

Broadly, I'm using the term to refer to the kind of thing one does with a map and a compass to find location in planar space. However, my problem is probably more closely modeled on something like seismography or "passive sonar" except in two dimensional space. Here's the problem.

I have three sound sensors at known, fixed, locations. The "target" emits a noise somewhere in the space between these sensors. In due course, the sound reaches each of the sensors and the absolute time of these events is noted (by a computer!)[image: Triangulation]

Now, some notes:

- The whole thing is entirely planar, I don't have a third dimension to worry about
- I can position the three sensors to form an equilateral triangle, or put them on three vertices of a square, if either makes the math easier, mostly, I'm in complete control of the positions of the sensors, and there aren't any obstacles or the like
- I know with modest accuracy the speed of sound in the medium this is all happening in, but I have a feeling that a solution should be possible without that information, instead relying only on the fact that the speed of sound is constant across the medium
- I don't know the absolute time that the target emitted the sound, so the first knowledge about the event is when the first sensor responds. In effect, I have to treat that as time zero, and the only "real" input information (other than the geometry of the sensors, and possibly the speed of sound) is the two differential times, marked delta t 1 (green) and delta t 2 (purple) in the diagram.

I've tried a number of doodles hoping to solve this, but even just trying to plot the locus of possible points from one pair of sensors kept leading me to very messy worse-than-quadratic equations involving way too many squares and roots of compound expressions, and I have no idea if I'm even on the right track. Even if I solved that part, I'd still have to find a point by solving two of these equations simultaneously and given that my math ended not long after high school and that was forty years ago, I'm struggling badly!

On one hand, it would be most rewarding if I could solve this myself, so hints and references are welcome, but on the other hand, my main interest is in building the device and so an actual solution would be totally welcome too. I'll let you decide if you think this is an interesting investigation for me.

EDIT:
So, I'm failing to understand Claude's help. I'm trying to take the equations he provided (6) and (7) and "(6) and (7), eliminate X and Y which then express as linear functions of T." But I don't understand how to do this. I've written out as far as I can get in the image:

[image]

But this gives me a function that relates Y and T, both of which are unknowns, but I don't understand how to eliminate Y to get at an expression for T (which is what I think Claude is telling me to do, though I admit I'm wondering if I've totally misunderstood). To be fair, even if I did have a function for T, I'm not entirely sure I see how the next step of "plug the results in 1" proceeds, but I'm not there yet anyway.

Comment: I take it your are trying to solve for both the time and position of the event?

Comment: This comes down to finding (or, in real life, estimating) the intersection of three hyperbolas. Search for “TDOA (Time Difference of Arrival) geolocation” or “multilateration.’

Comment: You can suppose that the speed of sound in the medium is $1$ unit per second, so you can use distance instead of time.  That should give you a clue as to where the hyperbolas in @amd's comment come from.

Comment: @saulspatz, no, I only care about the location, not the time.
I'll investigate the answer from Claude Leibovici below and the hyperbolae observation and see what I find. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have $3$ sensors located at coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$ which receive the information at times $t_i$ and you look for the coordinates $(X,Y)$ where the event happened at time $T$. Let $v$ be the speed of sound.

Consider the three equations
$$(X-x_1)^2+(Y-y_1)^2 = v^2 (t_1-T)^2 \tag 1$$
$$(X-x_2)^2+(Y-y_2)^2 = v^2 (t_2-T)^2 \tag 2$$
$$(X-x_3)^2+(Y-y_3)^2 = v^2 (t_3-T)^2 \tag 3$$

Subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$ and $(3)$, simplify and group terms. You will get
$$2(x_1-x_2)X+2(y_1-y_2)Y+2(t_2-t_1)v^2 T=(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2)+v^2(t_2^2-t_1^2)=2R_{12} \tag 4$$
$$2(x_1-x_3)X+2(y_1-y_3)Y+2(t_3-t_1)v^2 T=(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_3^2+y_3^2)+v^2(t_3^2-t_1^2)=2R_{13} \tag 5$$ that is to say
$$(x_1-x_2)X+(y_1-y_2)Y+(t_2-t_1)v^2 T=R_{12} \tag 6$$
$$(x_1-x_3)X+(y_1-y_3)Y+(t_3-t_1)v^2 T=R_{13} \tag 7$$ 
From $(6)$ and $(7)$, eliminate $X$ and $Y$ which then express as linear functions of $T$. Plug the results in $(1)$; this gives a quadratic equation in $T$. Solve it and go back to  $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Ah, yes, these look similar in complexity to what I was coming up with, though I'd left out speed and they weren't the same. One question; what are R12 and R13? I haven't studied your answer yet, so if I realize it's obvious when I do, I apologize!

And does the world get any simpler if I don't care about the time? (I actually don't...) Meanwhile, thanks for this Claude!

Comment: @TobyEggitt. $(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2)+v^2(t_2^2-t_1^2)=2R_{12}$ and look for the other one. It is not so complex (I used this for decades). For sure the problem is simpler with distances than with time.

Comment: Complexity is relative :) Hopefully I'll work out R12 soon. I'll get to work and come back if I fall flat on my face (or if I succeed!)

Comment: @TobyEggitt. Yes, please : let me know ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Well, I have to admit I'm struggling. I finally managed to reproduce what you've already done, so at least I actually understand that. And I know that "R12" is a shorthand for "half the right hand side result of the subtraction of 1 from 2" ;) But when I try to work with 6 and 7 I'm failing. I started down the path of re-writing 6 to give me an expression for X, with the intention of patching that into 7. But a) it's huge (well, that might be OK I suppose) and b) this route only eliminates X, it does nothing for Y. Can you give a hint as to how I do this elimination?

Comment: @ClaudeLiebovici yes, I'm beaten. I'm pretty sure that I only ever learned to use one equation to create an expression for one unknown, and substitute that into one other equation, resulting in one less unknown. I can do that more than once, but in this case we only seem to have two equations to work with (unless I misunderstand something--we can't go back to the originals, right, because they contain no new information, I think). I've tried searching for this topic, but found nothing new. So, if you're willing to spill the beans, I'm ready to admit that I have to learn this, not solve it!

Comment: Oh, but now it occurs to me that maybe I do have more information. Can I create a third equation of the form blah-blah = R23? So far, we have two equations giving expressions you had called R12 and R13 obtained by subracting 1 from 2 and 1 from 3. Would there be "information" in the result of subtracting 2 from 3, and could I use that perhaps? I might give that a go...

Comment: Sigh, no all I did that time was prove that 0 = 0 :( Well, I guess it's good to be sure, but it didn't move me forwards. I suppose on the bright side, I did manage to eliminate X and Y, but I also eliminated everything else!

Comment: At this point, I have developed software for an iterative solution to this. Basically, make guesses at the "unseen" time (that is, the time delay before the first sensor picks up. Then based on that guess, I calculate where the point would have been relative to two sensors, and then two other sensors (one sensor is shared in these two calculations). If the points are approximately coincident, then that's my point. I'll try to write this up with some diagrams in a few days. At this point, the software is pretty crude with several non-trivial limitations, but works. Thanks all for the hints!

Comment: @TobyEggitt. I do not undertand why you need an iterative process. If you know $v$, the solution is direct. Give me (if you wish) an example that is to say $3$ triplets $(x_i,y_,t_i)$ and $v$. I should update my answer later. Cheers and **Happy New Year !**

Comment: I don't *need* an iterative solution, just a "general" one :) I succeeded in creating an iterative one but so far have failed entirely at producing an algebraic one :(

I need to be able to write a function (computer code) that will solve any set of data that shows up, when it shows up, so solving a specific example isn't my goal. I'd still enjoy learning how to create a general solution to those simultaneous equations, but as I noted, although I managed (eventually!) to follow and reproduce what you had so generously led with above, I was utterly unable to progress any further.

Comment: @TobyEggitt. I do not see the problem : the solution is fully explicit

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, because I don't understand how to use it. I appear to have two simultaneous equations ( 6 and 7 ) in three unknowns X, Y, and T. I have no idea how to solve that, much less turn it into a function in a programming language. Like I said, I pretty much quit academic mathematics study a bit shy of 40 years ago, and that was only first year engineering, but I don't think I ever knew how to solve something with more unknowns than equations. If you can point me at a reference, or somehow show me what's obvious that I'm missing, I would be most grateful.

Comment: @ClaudeLiebovici I think my problem is that I never actually got to "the solution". Your original input left me with "homework" to do; specifically to "eliminate X and Y from (6) and (7) and plug the results back into (1)." But I wasn't up to the task, so I don't have the "solution" to which you refer. I've had to admit that I don't know how to proceed, but if you're still willing, I'm ready to be handed the answer now; it's clear that I'm not going to get there solo, even with the help you've so kindly given.

Comment: @TobyEggitt. I just repeat myself : use $(6)$ and $(7)$ fo get $X$ and $Y$ as functions of $T$. Plug in $(1)$ which becomes a quadratic in $T$; compute the roots and check the results to select the proper $T$. The go back to $X$ and $Y$ and replace $T$. by its value. The problem would be simpler using the distances instead of the times.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts on my behalf Claude, but the problem is, I don't understand how to do that. Are you able to show me how to get x and y as functions of T? Could you write out that function for me? I'm assuming that you're describing an algebraic transformation here, not putting values in? I need an algebraic solution (well, I think I do) because I need to code this as software, and I don't think I can do algebra, as opposed to doing computations, in code.

Comment: So, I've added to my original question a description of what I think you're telling me, and illustrating what happens when I try to follow that guidance. It's entirely likely that I'm utterly misunderstanding, but hopefully this might help you see what I'm misunderstanding. Or in some way allow you to see what I'm doing wrong. Thank you again for your patience and help; I'm feeling very stupid right now :(

Comment: @ClaudeLiebovici sorry, I forgot to tag the last two comments. Hoping you might be able to guide me a bit more, I also added to my question hoping you might be able to see what it is that I'm not understanding. I just don't know how to follow your instructions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for your response (regarding my very similar question). So, I guess I'm not entirely following the last few steps "from (6) and (7), eliminate X and Y which then express as linear functions of T. Plug the results in (1); this gives a quadratic equation in T. Solve it and go back to X and Y.". It's probably something simple I'm missing, but this is certainly *way* outside my field of expertise. I guess, if I were to have paper and pencil infront of me, how exactly would I go about this? Thank you, again.

Comment: @K_M. Ping me tomorrow morning (it is 9:00pm here) and we can meet in a chat room if you want. Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Let me know if you're available to talk.