# Understanding and implementing a multilateration localization algorithm.

Tags: algorithms, physics, mathematical-physics, regression, least-squares

I’m trying to implement a Time Delay of Arrival Multilateration algorithm. However, I’m struggling to understand the concept on the level necessary to produce an actual implementation.

For reference, my problem is as follows:

Given the location of three receivers, and the time at which each receiver “saw” some signal, determine the location of the source. We can assume the source and the receivers are in a plane, and that the curvature of the earth is negligible. We also know the velocity of the signal.

My understanding of the subject is that this somehow involves fitting three hyperbola and determining their intersection (see [Measurement Geometry (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration#Measurement_geometry_and_related_factors) and [Solution Algorithms (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration#Solution_algorithms)

In practice, how would this work? To what equation do I fit the hyperbola? In what way would I perform the fitting (will least squares regression work here?). Overall, why does this work?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049933/triangulation-position-location-on-a-plane/3050065#3050065 could be a starting point. If you want more, just tell.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for your comment. This is very informative, however I must admit I'm still struggling to take this from the answer you've given to an implementation (unfortunately, this sort of thing is considerably outside my area of expertise). I'm particularly struggling with the last bit of your answer (I made a more detailed comment there)